# URL Rewrite mobiles to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, mod-rewrite

I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mobile%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /mobile/$1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|iphone|ipod" [NC]   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [L]
```

**The problem** is that when mobiles gets redirected the images from the root won't load. I'm using this because I need to add the subdirectory (mobile) to the url example:

```
www.example.com/sub/file.php
www.example.com/mobile/sub/file.php
```

This code works but the images in the root don't show even do the path to the src shows that theres no /mobile/ added with the htaccess rules. if I add the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f to the secund line of conds like in the secund edit the images on the root are loading but  I never get redirected to the mobile subdirectory since all of the urls exist.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mobile%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /mobile/$1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|iphone|ipod" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the ALL files exist in the root directory, but not all in the mobile directory, you have two options.

The most simple one is, to make an exception for files, to not rewrite them to mobile.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)
```

The second option is to perform two steps: First rewrite everything to /mobile. Than if the file does not exist, rewrite it back to root, but add a mark so that it's not being rewritten again to mobile!

```
#In case of a mobile device, rewrite everything to mobile. (windows phone = wp or wo7 / wp8)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|iphone|ipod|wp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mobile
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !noRewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /mobile/$1 [L]

#In case the file exists, good, else rewrite back to non-mobile.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mobile
RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)$ /$1?noRewrite [L]
```

The above htaccess was tested, whereas image.jpg was in the root and index.php both in root as /mobile. index.php showed the image perfectly.

Comment: thank for your answer, but the images still dont load. In the code should I write the source of the image like src="http://example.com/file.jpg" or src="../file.jpg"

Comment: In my opinion, it is best to use static URL's when using htaccess. Though assuming the html/script file is located in the mobile directory and file.jpg in the root, both links are correct.

Comment: thank again for trying. I add more info to the question I hope this helps. The images are now loading but I'not been redirected since all of the url exist.

Comment: Thanks four your time,I use the second option and it works like a charm.Sorry that I can't vote up since I don't have the reputation, is there something else I can do for you?

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Have fun with the code and the website :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jefrey, your response is the closest to my scenario above all I have seen so far. Just to add to the initial question asked. Say there is an htaccess in the home dir and another htaccess in the mobile dir,

1. Which of the 2 files will contain the code above?
2. What do I put in the other file?

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer

Comment: When you have more rep, you can add this as a comment...  Until that time, its better asked in its own question....